# i need to count how many below average salary the table has

Tags: hive, hql

```
SELECT
    *, 
    COUNT (AnnualSalary < avg(AnnualSalary)) AS Count 
FROM Assessment 
GROUP BY ServiceType
```

This is a Hive query, im trying to count how many records from table earn less that the average salary

Comment: SELECT * , COUNT (AnnualSalary) AS Count FROM Assessment GROUP BY ServiceType HAVING AnnualSalaray<AVG(AnnualSalary)

Answer (score 0):

First, distribute rows into different partitions according their `ServiceType`. Without specifying `ORDER BY` and window specification, the default is `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`.

Then, apply the aggregation `AVG` as an analytic function over each window to get the average AnnualSalary for each partition. Consequently we get to know whether a record's AnnualSalary is below the average of its partition.

Finally, a count on the intermediate result set.

```sql
SELECT
    SERVICETYPE,
    SUM(ISBELOW)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        CASE 
            WHEN ANNUALSALARY < AVG(ANNUALSALARY) OVER (PARTITION BY SERVICETYPE) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS ISBELOW
    FROM ASSESSMENT
) TMP
GROUP BY SERVICETYPE
;
```

Note, a `HAVING` clause is for filtering after `GROUP BY`, and details for individual rows are lost before the filter.